# Code documentation with Sphinx and RinohType only on the right third of the page

Tags: python-sphinx, rinohtype

I'm struggling with the formatting of the RinohType generated PDF document of my code documentation. How can I change the format of the PDF document for the following example.

Everything of the class description is on the right side to the constructor's definition.

[image: image of PDF]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was caused by recent changes to how objects with labels are rendered. The *Sphinx* style sheet was adjusted to fix this in [rinohtype 0.5.2](https://pypi.org/project/rinohtype/0.5.2/) (thanks to you pointing out this issue!).

If you can't upgrade to 0.5.2, you can fix this by [extending the style sheet](http://www.mos6581.org/rinohtype/master/basicstyling.html#extending-an-existing-style-sheet) and overriding the [label_max_width](http://www.mos6581.org/rinohtype/master/style/rinoh.flowable.LabeledFlowableStyle.html#rinoh.flowable.LabeledFlowableStyle.label_max_width) style property for the [object description](http://www.mos6581.org/rinohtype/master/stylesheets.html#default-matcher) style. A value of *none* places no limits on the label width and will always render the description to the right. Setting *label_max_width* to a dimension will force the the description to be rendered below the label if it exceeds the specified width.

`mystyle.rts`:

```ini
[STYLESHEET]
name=MyStyle
base=sphinx

[object description]
label_max_width=10pt
```

To instruct rinohtype to use this style sheet, you first need to create a [template configuration file](http://www.mos6581.org/rinohtype/master/basicstyling.html#configure-templates) that references it:

`mytemplate.rtt`:

```ini
[TEMPLATE_CONFIGURATION]
name = my template configuration
template = book
stylesheet = mystyle.rts
```

Finally, reference this template configuration file from [`rinoh_documents`](http://www.mos6581.org/rinohtype/master/sphinx.html#confval-rinoh_documents) in your project's `conf.py`:

```python
rinoh_documents = [
    dict(doc='index', target='manual', template='mytemplate.rtt'),
]
```

Comment: Thank you for the hint with the style sheet. However, after a longer search I didn't find the way how I create an own style. 

Does I understand it correctly that I have to derive my own style from one of the default and override only the label_max_width. Like this .rts file.

[STYLESHEET]
name=MyStyle
base=sphinx

[VARIABLES]
label_max_width=10pt

But where I have to register this? How can I use this style? Unfortunately, this is still unclear to me.

Comment: @ThomasK This may indeed be difficult to discern from the current documentation. I've updated the answer with more detailed instructions.

Comment: It works. :).  Many thanks for your help. Now I have a really beautiful documentation. :)

Comment: @BrechtMachiels, what is [object description] here? How do I give my custom style. For example, I want to change the width and height of the logo?